# psql: How do I not record a single command into history

Tags: postgresql, psql

In bash there is a setting (usually on by default) that makes it so that any commands that are preceded by a space aren't recorded into the history file.

Is there anything analogous in psql?

Comment: Cool feature in bash. And no, not as far as I know. A patch might be accepted if you submitted one. However, check the `readline` docs, maybe there's a way to do it with readline...

Comment: @CraigRinger So I poked around in the source and found an answer.  It uses the same variable name and settings as the Bash version of the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is possible.

Add `\set HISTCONTROL ignorespace` to your .psqlrc file.

Then when you precede a command with a space, say setting a password, it won't be added to the history file.

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> HISTCONTROL
>
> If this variable is set to ignorespace, lines which begin with a space are not entered into the history list. If set to a value of
>   ignoredups, lines matching the previous history line are not entered.
>   A value of ignoreboth combines the two options. If unset, or if set to
>   none (or any other value than those above), all lines read in
>   interactive mode are saved on the history list.

Comment: Nice find, thanks for looking it up. I've been using psql for years and had no idea.